# How to get the first date of each day of a table in PostgreSQL and convert it into a JSON

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

As the question says, I want to get the first value obtained from each date of a table that has "N" number of items and columns, but has a `timestamp field without time zone` and those values I want to concatenate in a JSON which is within an array.

The query receives an interval of days type `Date`. The `start date` and the `end date`

For example, I have a table with

```sql
ID | fecha               
1   "2019-05-18 13:55:54"
2   "2019-05-18 13:57:22"
3   "2019-05-18 13:57:37"
4   "2019-05-18 13:58:07"
5   "2019-05-18 13:58:37"
6   "2019-05-18 13:58:48"
7   "2019-05-19 13:55:54"
8   "2019-05-19 13:57:22"
9   "2019-05-19 13:57:37"
10  "2019-05-20 13:58:07"
11  "2019-05-20 13:58:37"
12  "2019-05-20 13:58:48"
```

And I want to get this if I pass for example `start_day : '2019-05-18'` and `end_date: '2019-05-20'`

**Expected result**

`[{"id" : 1, "fecha" :"2019-05-18 13:55:54"},{"id" : 7, "fecha" :"2019-05-19 13:55:54"},{"id" : 10, "fecha" :"2019-05-20 13:58:48"}]`

I will to use `json_agg` and `json_build_object` to get the JSON inside an Array, but I dont know how to get the first date of each day in a simple query. If you can help me with that I will appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `distinct on` to get the first entry per day, while still maintaining the full timestamp.

```
select json_agg(d) 
FROM (SELECT distinct on (fecha::date)
      json_build_object('id', id, 'fecha', fecha) as d
      FROM test
      ORDER BY fecha::date, fecha)
 sub;
                                                                 json_agg
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"id" : 1, "fecha" : "2019-05-18T13:55:54"}, {"id" : 7, "fecha" : "2019-05-19T13:55:54"}, {"id" : 10, "fecha" : "2019-05-20T13:58:07"}]
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply cast it to a date and group on it, selecting the min time stamp per date:

```
SELECT fecha::date, min(fecha)
FROM table
GROUP BY fecha::date
```

Casting to date effectively strips the time, giving you your "per day" requirement, then the first timestamp for that day is given by the min. Your id seem sequential; you can min that too because the min is on a day will also be the min timestamp. If there's any chance the id are not sequential leave a comment and I'll give a further advice